# apt-get fail with "Unpacking replacement diff"

Tags: apt

I tried to install TeXmacs today by follow commond:

```
sudo apt-get install texmacs
```

but those message come up:

```
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `diff' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
(Reading database ... 212095 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace diff 1:2.8.1-18 (using .../diff_1%3a2.8.1-18_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement diff ...
```

I have no idea why my computer stop at here.

I try to install other software but same message will come. How to solve it?

Then I type following:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock 
sudo mv /var/cache/apt/archives/diff_1%3a2.8.1-18_all.deb /var/tmp
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install texmacs
```

Seems not work:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  python-wxgtk2.8 ttf-symbol-replacement wine1.2-gecko cabextract
  ttf-mscorefonts-installer nvidia-settings python-wxversion
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  diff iamerican ispell libjpeg-progs librsvg2-bin libtiff-tools
  texlive-math-extra texmacs-common texmacs-extra-fonts transfig xaw3dg xfig
  xfig-libs
Suggested packages:
  spell libtiff-opengl xfig-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  iamerican ispell libjpeg-progs librsvg2-bin libtiff-tools texlive-math-extra
  texmacs texmacs-common texmacs-extra-fonts transfig xaw3dg xfig xfig-libs
The following packages will be upgraded:
  diff
1 upgraded, 13 newly installed, 0 to remove and 73 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 22.8MB of archives.
After this operation, 70.3MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-security/main libtiff-tools 3.9.2-2ubuntu0.6 [252kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe diff 1:2.8.1-18 [5,868B]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main ispell 3.1.20.0-7 [175kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main iamerican 3.1.20.0-7 [445kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main libjpeg-progs 7+really6b-15ubuntu1 [83.8kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/universe librsvg2-bin 2.26.3-0ubuntu1 [23.2kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main texlive-math-extra 2009-7ubuntu3 [7,121kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe texmacs-common 1:1.0.7.3-3 [3,879kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe texmacs 1:1.0.7.3-3 [1,944kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe texmacs-extra-fonts 0.2 [5,674kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main transfig 1:3.2.5.a-2.1 [608kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main xaw3dg 1.5+E-17build1 [176kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe xfig 1:3.2.5.b-1ubuntu1 [748kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe xfig-libs 1:3.2.5.b-1ubuntu1 [1,679kB]
Fetched 22.8MB in 1min 2s (366kB/s)                                            
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 
dpkg: warning: files list file for package `diff' missing, assuming package has no files currently installed.
(Reading database ... 212095 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace diff 1:2.8.1-18 (using .../diff_1%3a2.8.1-18_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement diff ...
```

Why I should upgrade diff package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the *.deb* file and try repairing `dpkg`

```
sudo mv /var/cache/apt/archives/diff_1%3a2.8.1-18_all.deb /var/tmp
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

EDIT: Please also have a look at the following bug report; it may apply to your situation: [bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/624229](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/624229)

Comment: Moving it to `/var/tmp` is not a good idea. Files in `/var/tmp` persist between boots, and in this way, it can get pretty full. Use `sudo apt-get clean` to clear all previously downloaded packages (not applications).

Comment: It's a matter of opinion. When dealing with such problems, I prefer playing it safe and keeping the package if I run into an unwanted reboot (`/tmp` purged) and/or lose internet connection (can't download packages).

Comment: Seems not ok, see updated. Is it because of the upgrading fail?

Comment: Please have a look at the following bug report; does it apply to your situation? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/624229

Comment: I exactly use a laptop as this man https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dpkg/+bug/624229/comments/28
Although I remove all USB device, I cannot install any package.

Comment: Can you run and post (not here, it will be long) `sudo dpkg --debug=3773 -i /var/cache/apt/archives/diff_1%3a2.8.1-18_all.deb` to see if you're having the same problem?

Comment: I resolve the problem by remove all usb device and reboot OS.